# Why does my attempt at backtracking to solve the balanced parentheses problem not work?

Tags: python, algorithm, backtracking

I'm not sure what I'm misunderstanding about backtracking.

Problem:

> Given n pairs of parentheses, write a function to generate all combinations of well-formed parentheses.

Example 1:

```
Input: n = 3
Output: ["((()))","(()())","(())()","()(())","()()()"]
```

Example 2:

```
Input: n = 1
Output: ["()"]
```

Constraints:

```
1 <= n <= 8
```

What I've tried so far (working code):

```
class Solution(object):
    def generateParenthesis(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: List[str]
        """
        balanced = []
        
        placement = []
        left = [')'] * n
        right = ['()'] * n
        
        def is_balanced(placement):
            open_list = ["[","{","("]
            close_list = ["]","}",")"]
            myStr = placement[0]
            stack = []
            for i in myStr:
                if i in open_list:
                    stack.append(i)
                elif i in close_list:
                    pos = close_list.index(i)
                    if ((len(stack) > 0) and
                        (open_list[pos] == stack[len(stack)-1])):
                        stack.pop()
                    else:
                        return False 
            if len(stack) == 0:
                return True 
            else:
                return False 

        
        def solve(left, right, results):
            #goal or base case
            if len(left) == 0 or len(right) == 0:
                balanced.extend(results)
                return 
            for i in range(2*n):
                l = left.pop(0)
                placement.append(l)
                if is_balanced(placement):
                    #recurse on decision
                    solve(left, right, results)
                r = right.pop(0)
                placement.append(r)
                if is_balanced(placement):
                    #recurse on decision
                    solve(left, right, results)
                #undo decision
                left.append(l)
                right.append(r)
                placement.pop(-1)
        
        solve(left, right, results)
        return balanced
```

The code seems to return empty array for all cases.

Comment: Hi! It looks like you just dumped your whole code and expect someone else to debug it for you. Have you tried debugging it yourself? Have you identified which parts of the code worked correctly, and which didn't? Does function `is_balanced` work? Does function `solve` work? Also, is there a good reason why the two functions `is_balanced` and `solve` are defined inside the body of another function?

Comment: @Stef yes the code runs, are you familiar with backtracking this is the basic template for backtracking problems. is_balanced checks for valid parenthesis.

Comment: What other code? There is no `isVallid` in your post. Have you tested function `is_balanced` on some balanced and unbalanced strings, to test that it does return the correct results that you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the extra complication is necessary. We can have a recursion that keeps track and doesn't let the count of right parentheses (`r`) exceed the count of the left (`n`) at any point during the construction:

```js
function f(n, s='', r=n){
  return r == 0 ? [s] : (n == 0 ? [] : f(n-1, s+'(', r))
    .concat(r > n ? f(n, s+')', r-1) : [])
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(3)))
```